# In iOS, how to open a YouTube user or channel (not video) in the native app?

Tags: ios, url, youtube, native, youtube-channels

I know how to open the YouTube native app for a particular video with these url strings:

> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEO_IDENTIFIER
>   http://www.youtube.com/v/VIDEO_IDENTIFIER

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/YouTubeLinks/YouTubeLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899-CH8-SW1)

But how to open the YouTube app with a particular user's page?  An equivalent web browser url looks like this:  https://www.youtube.com/user/someUser

Using the this url opens the Youtube mobile web app in Safari.  But I'd like it to open in the native YouTube app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the custom url schema defined as follows: youtube://user/[username]. I didn't find documentation for this but discovered it by means of experimentation. Here is a also a cool way to test if the native App is installed.

```
NSString* social   = @"http://www.youtube.com/user/CanadianMortgageApp";
NSString* socialApp = @"youtube://user/CanadianMortgageApp";

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:socialApp]]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:socialApp]];
} else {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:social]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not possible at this time. (Source: extensive personal testing.)

Answer (score 0):

Using the custom URL for the channel worked for me:

```
 NSURL *youTubeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"youtube://www.youtube.com/c/yourcustomurl"];
        if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:youTubeURL]) {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:youTubeURL];
        } else {
            NSURL *youTubeWebURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com/c/yourcustomurl"];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:youTubeWebURL];
        }
```